# Is there an online service to count open and closing brackets?

Tags: syntax-error

Is anyone familiar with an online service where I can paste some code, and it tells me

1. If all my brackets are in place - Not missing/adding a close bracket?
2. According the language syntax - that the code is right?

   - I agree that most editors color scheme/and or give you an error. This specific one does not :-) It's called: Notepad ^^  - Which I use a lot, but still. If such a service exists - it can help no matter what IDE you use. If you have a piece of code you want to check - and don't feel like opening the IDE

Example (There is a missing bracket on the '3' part):

```
IF( OR( ISBLANK(BillingCountry), UPPER(BillingCountry) = 'UNITED STATES' , UPPER(BillingCountry) = 'USA', UPPER(BillingCountry) = 'US', UPPER(BillingCountry) = 'U.S.', UPPER(BillingCountry) = 'U.S.A.' ), 

IF ( OR( BillingState = 'CA' , BillingState = 'WA' , BillingState = 'OR' , BillingState = 'ID' , BillingState = 'NV' , BillingState = 'MT' , BillingState = 'WY' , BillingState = 'CO' , BillingState = 'UT' , BillingState = 'AZ' , BillingState = 'NM'), 
"1 - West" 
,
IF ( OR( BillingState = 'IL' , BillingState = 'ND' , BillingState = 'SD' , BillingState = 'MI' , BillingState = 'NE' , BillingState = 'IA' , BillingState = 'KS' , BillingState = 'OK' , BillingState = 'TX' , BillingState = 'IL' , BillingState = 'MN' , BillingState = 'OH' , BillingState = 'WI' , BillingState = 'IN' , BillingState = 'CANADA'), 
"2 - MIDWEST" 
, 
IF( OR( BillingState = 'NY' , BillingState = 'ME' , BillingState = 'NH' , BillingState = 'MA' , BillingState = 'RI' , BillingState = 'CT' , BillingState = 'NJ' , BillingState = 'DE' , BillingState = 'D.C.' , BillingState = 'VA' , BillingState = 'WVA' , BillingState = 'NC' , BillingState = 'SC' , BillingState = 'GA' , BillingState = 'FL' , BillingState = 'VT' , BillingState = 'PA' , BillingState = 'MD' , BillingState = 'KY' , BillingState = 'TN' , BillingState = 'AR' , BillingState = 'AL' , BillingState = 'MS' , BillingState = 'LS'), 
"3 - East" 
, 
"Unknown" ) )
, 
IF( LEN(BillingCountry) > 0, "4 - International", "Unknown") 
)
```

Comment: What editor do you use? Most of them are colouring code and are showing if there is missing brackets ou main structure problems.

Answer (score 11):

This might help [ideone.com](http://ideone.com). But you could just install Notepad++

Answer (score 6):

This website might help to satisfy the 1st point : http://www.balancebraces.com/

This website has options to check Braces: { },Parentheses: ( ), Brackets: [ ], and  Tags: < > and color them for easy identification.